# how to get all the array values related to key and values in php array

Tags: php, codeigniter, recursion

I have the following array

```
Array
(
    [22] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1074
            [1] => 1926
        )

    [1772] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1080
            [1] => 1921
        )

    [1926] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1772
        )

    [1080] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1833
        )
)
```

I want all the data related to key 1926. Here in above 1926 has value 1772 then in this key has 2 values 1080 and 1921 I have to check both keys and so on.

The result I want:
array(

```
[0]=>1772
[1]=>1080
[2]=>1921
[3]=>1833
.....
```

)

I have tried many solutions, but I am not getting desired response, I have created the below code that returns me only one value 1772

```
function arrayTraverse($targetKey, $array, $returndata=[]) 
{
    foreach($array as $key=>$values){
        if($targetKey == $key){
            unset($array[$targetKey]);
            if(is_array($values))
            {
                foreach($values as $val){
                    $returndata = array_merge($returndata, array($val));
                    arrayTraverse($val, $array, $returndata);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $returndata;
}
```

Here at last I am getting only [0]=>1772

Comment: **I want to** is not a question. It just informs us that you want us to do the heavy lifting for you.
Where are you stuck? What have you researched? What have you tried? To be clear, we'll help you at stackoverflow but we're not a free do-my-thinking service 
See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have tried many solutions, but I am not getting desired response

function arrayTraverse($targetKey, $array, $returndata=[]) 
{
    foreach($array as $key=>$values){
        if($targetKey == $key){
            unset($array[$targetKey]);
            if(is_array($values))
            {
                foreach($values as $val){
                    $returndata = array_merge($returndata, array($val));
                    arrayTraverse($val, $array, $returndata);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $returndata;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach array
  foreach subArray 
     if isset(array[value])
       subArray[key] &= array[value]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the above mine problem, below is the code that will get the exact data

```
function arrayTraverse($reportingusersArr, $targetkey, $resultarr=[], $checkvalues=[]){
    $uservalues = $reportingusersArr[$targetkey];
    if($uservalues){
        unset($reportingusersArr[$targetkey]);
        $resultarr[$targetkey] = $uservalues;
        $lastResultvalue = $uservalues;
        foreach($uservalues as $keya=>$uva){
            $checkvalues[] = $uva;
        }

        foreach($uservalues as $key=>$uv){
            $elementkey = array_search($targetkey, $checkvalues);
            unset($checkvalues[$elementkey]);
            return arrayTraverse($reportingusersArr, $uv, $resultarr, $checkvalues);
        }
    }
    else{
        $othercheckval = $checkvalues;
        foreach($checkvalues as $key3=>$uv2){
            $elementkey = array_search($uv2, $othercheckval);
            unset($othercheckval[$elementkey]);
            return arrayTraverse($reportingusersArr, $uv2, $resultarr, $othercheckval);
        }
    }
    $finalarray = [];
    foreach($resultarr as $fkey=>$fvaluearr){
        foreach($fvaluearr as $fval)
        {
            $finalarray[] = $fval;
        }
    }
    return $finalarray;
}
```